# Application not getting suspended

Tags: xcode, ios

I am observing a strange behavior. I am executing this method:

```
- (void) aLongRunningMethod: (NSString*) input {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        //Sleep for 1 second
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1];
        NSLog(@"Progress: %d", i);
    }
}
```

In the iOS simulator, I hit the home button. I expect the thread to be suspended right away. But, that does not happen. The method keeps going. I am pretty sure that that is not the designed behavior. Is this a defect in the simulator or am I misunderstood about application's state transition.

Comment: Are you running through XCode? In which case you will be attached to the debugger which will hinder normal thread start/stop behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Anything running on the current/main runloop with have a chance to finish.  But the operating system reserved the rights to kill anything taking too long.

If you execute that method on a background thread it will suspend right away when you press the **Home** button.

Try it:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(aLongRunningMethod:) withObject:@"Running in background"];
```